# Unexpected MongoDB "OR" query behaviour

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I'm testing out spring-data and it's mongodb support.

I have a question about the query creation when using or-queries. Consider the following:

```
Query query = new Query().or(new Query(where("receiverId").is(userId)), new Query(where("requesterId").is(userId)));
query.and(where("status").is(status));
```

This will result in the following mongodb query:

```
 "$or" : [ { "receiverId" : { "$oid" : "4d78696025d0d46b42d9c579"}} , { "requesterId" : { "$oid" : "4d78696025d0d46b42d9c579"}}] , "status" : "REQUESTED"}
```

This returns zero results while one is expected. Running this query in mongodb command results in following error:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $oid", "code" : 10068 }
```

Modifying the query and running it in mongodb command works fine:

```
{ "$or" : [ { "receiverId" : ObjectId("4d78696025d0d46b42d9c579")} , { "requesterId" : ObjectId("4d78696025d0d46b42d9c579")}] , "status" : "REQUESTED"}
```

Notice the use of ObjectId("...") instead of $oid.

Am I going about something the wrong way? Maybe setting up the query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you inspecting that query variable at runtime or is that what you are seeing in MongoDB's logs?

Int he C# driver, if you inspect the query variable, you see $oid as well, but that is not the actual query that is sent to the server.  At some point, it changes that to a valid MongoDB query.

If you are running on linux, you may want to start up `mongosniff` which will show you realtime queries, updates and inserts as they happen. If you are on Windows, you should start up `mongod.exe` with `-vvvv` flag which will enable it to log every query, update, insert, or command to the log file.

Then you can actually see the exact query that is being submitted.

Comment: Thank you! Used mongosniff and ObjectId is actually used.